# String.Format() function as seen in vb.net but for mono

Tags: c#, vb.net, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I am using mono-develop for unity3d and I have came across a situation in which I would want to use the string.format() function from vb.net and I can't seem to find anything of use for use in mono which as unity developers know, is a dialect of c#. I want to make a stop clock for the game I am making but Time.realtimeSinceStartup has too many decimal places and so that is why I want to use string.format() (or at least something that does the same thing. I also need it to count in terms of seconds and minutes.

Comment: I have used string.Format() many times in Unity3D and don't have any problem with that. Is there any error or something?

Comment: `String.Format()` definitely is present in Mono. If you are having problems getting it to work, please edit your question so that it includes [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, and explain _precisely_ what's wrong with the code. If there are any error messages, include the _exact text_ of those error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Format is normally used to... format strings e.g.

```
string.Format("The time is {0}", timeVariable);
```

If you want to shorten your stop clock value you can use

```
timeVariable.Tostring("#.##");
```

This would show your variable to 2 decimal places.

Comment: thanks for your solution, it now counts the seconds to 2 decimal places. The only thing i need it to do now is to count in terms of minutes and seconds etc as i want to create a leaderboard in the game. Any ideas?

Comment: You could store minute variables by dividing seconds by 60. Then use your string.Format method to make a minutes and seconds string. e.g. string.Format("The time is {0}:{1}", minutesVariable, secondsVariable);